# Resource suggestion for astronomy

Tags: resource-recommendations, astronomy, education

Can someone suggest a good astronomy book with mathematical explanation for a high school student? i need to develop my interest with more mathematical and other complex nature of the celestial bodies

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24965/2451 and links therein.